# GDI/GDI+ in WPF applications: performance and good praticles

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, gdi

There are some GDI's objects to do some works with images in WPF, but these objects generate memory leaks easily and other errors (i.e MILERR_WIN32ERROR).

1. What would be high level alternatives to do the same work without using GDI?
2. Would be GDI bad for performance in a WPF application, once WPF uses DirectX beneath?

Comment: A high level alternative is to leave it up to another programmer to write this code.  One that knows how to do it right without leaks and errors.  Certainly plenty of GDI wrappers around, it is entirely unclear why you need this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be high level alternatives to do the same work without using GDI?

It really depends, but ideally, you'd do the work using WPF's api instead.

> Would be GDI bad for performance in a WPF application, once WPF uses DirectX beneath?

There's always going to be extra conversion between WPF's image formats and `System.Drawing`, as WPF doesn't use GDI.  This is going to cause some extra overhead to map back and forth.